# Заменить символ в System.String

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Нужно заменить в строке все символы `'х'` на `'F'`, пробовал так:

```
String^ tempString = textBox1->Text;

for (size_t i = 0; i < tempString->ToString()->Length; i++)
{
    if (tempString[i] == L'x');
    {
        tempString->SubString(i)->Replace(L'x', L'F');
    }
}
```

Ожидаемого результата не получил. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Метка c++ здесь кажется лишняя. Все таки C++CLI это совсем другой язык.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В .NET строки неизменяемые.

Поэтому `Substring` и `Replace` возвращают вам *новую* строку, а старая не меняется. Поэтому ваш код ничего не делает.

С другой стороны, вы не должны проходить по строке посимвольно, за вас уже всё сделано. Функция [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx) заменяет сразу все вхождения одного символа на другой.

Пишите просто так, без всякого цикла:

```
tempString = tempString->Replace(L'x', L'F');
```

Comment: И да, C++/CLI — это извращение. Пишете на .NET — переходите на C#.

Comment: та уж понял что извращения)

Comment: `std::string::substr` тоже возвращает новую строку.